# How to import dotenv data and npm modules in script.js

Tags: javascript

```js
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = dotenv.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY
```

I tried to import data from .env and this error is thrown

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

The same thing happened when I installed some npm packages and tried to import them

I've added an type attribute of module to my script tag

```html
    <script src="./script.js" defer type="module"></script>
```

and now I get this error

"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dotenv". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

If I use "/" or "./" to change the import path I get a new error

net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Does enyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: dotenv is only supposed to be used on the server, not the browser.

Comment: is there any equivalent file for the browser?

Comment: No, the idea is that these variables are not visible to the client.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know , you can initialize a script on package.json after you npm init.
But you cant initialize npm on a script.
In my point of view it doesnt make sense
But for more info you can always read NPM DOCS

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to require and load `dotenv` in your application code when you are using the ES module. Instead of using import, you need to use this solution.

```
$ node -r dotenv/config script.js
```

where `-r` means `--require`